# spring integration activemq warm up connections

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I wrote a sample code using jms spring-integration, such that

```
request => app-a => activemq => app-b => activemq => app-a => response
```

When i execute a test on the above, the first request to response takes > 10 ms whereas subsequent request to response take 4ms. Is it possible to warm up the connections using spring-integration to improve the first request to response time ~4ms ? Also is there anything else/concepts that i can incorporate to improve the performance. (Note: I use activemq's PooledConnectionFactory instead of CachingConnectionFactory)